# Detect user restrictions for app store installation

Tags: ios, app-store

If you have a link to the app store in your app that follows the itms:// convention, is it possible to check if the user has any restrictions related to installing apps?

Tried `-[UIApplication canOpenURL:]` but that returns `YES`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately not allowed via Apple's apis